# ping / pong pattern for infura websocket

Tags: web3js, nodejs, infura, websocket, server-side

Infura websockets disconnect after an hour of in-activity so they suggest you ping / pong the connection at an interval less then an hour.

My problem is I'm new to server-side programming and don't know how to ping the websocket connection from my back-end (node.js).

When googling I found this framework of code (below). Is this what I'd put in my back-end to 'ping' the connection?

I'm unclear if the conditional **socket.readyState !== 1** is universal/'the norm' for all websockets in JS. Same with **socket.send("heartbeat")**. If it is then I assume it would work for Infura as well.

If anyone already has a ping pattern set-up I'd love to hear your insight!

```
let socket = null;

function connect_socket() {
  socket = new WebSocket(ws_url);
  socket.on("close", connect_socket); // <- rise from your grave!
  heartbeat();
}

function heartbeat() {
  if (!socket) return;
  if (socket.readyState !== 1) return;
  socket.send("heartbeat");
  setTimeout(heartbeat, 550000); 
}

connect_socket();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am stuck at the same point, using Infura socket to listen contract events, could you please suggest if you figure out this issue 2 years ago?